# Main method not found error

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I am new to jdbc and i'm try to connect to by database form IDE.The code below is what i wrote;

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample","app","app");
        preparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select name,zip,discount_code from customer where customer_id=?");
        ps.setInt(1,Interger.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            jTextField2.setText(rs.getString(1));
            jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(2));
            jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(rs.getString(3));
        }                                        
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        ex.PrintStackTrace();
    }catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new jdfrm().setVisible(true));
            }
        }
    }
```

**The error is..class "frm1.jdfrm" does not have a main method**

Comment: I don't have the points to do it yet, but you (or someone) should re-tag this to java or jdbc, not J.

Answer (score 1):

your `main` form is inside the `private void jButton1ActionPerformed`.. check the parenthesis

Comment: Though why does a nested method compile? That's certainly odd.

Comment: because you can have a 'main' method in every class. If you want to execute it, though, it needs to be in a public class and it has to be visible.

Comment: @Francis - did it really compile **without errors**? Some IDEs compile as much as possible, inserting an Error throw (Unresolved compilation problem) at the error point.

Comment: @Carlos, yes, Eclipse inserts the runtime error, but it also shows the compile error.  Don't know about other IDEs though.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets look like they are not right.  You need another closing before the main method.